# QTP/UFT: Comparing two excelsheets easy and performant using VB

Tags: excel, vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

I want to compare 2 Excel-Sheets in VB.
I know how to open these sheets in QTP/UFT
I know how to get the ranges of all cells.
But I do not know a performant way to compare these 2 sheets (ranges).

If a Value in 2nd Sheet is different to the corresponding value in first sheet it shall be inserted in the corresponding cell of 2nd Sheet.
I can parse all cells in serial to compare with the corresponding cell, but this is not very performant.

I want to compare it in following way:

```
If not (sheet1.range() equals sheet2.range()) then
  if not (Sheet1.range.Row equals sheet2.range.row) then
    if not (Sheet1.range.Row.cells equals Sheet2.range.Row.cells) then
      Sheet2.range.Row.cells.value = Sheet1.range.Row.cells.value
```

All Values could be in different rows and cells but there are corresponding ID in first Column and in the Header of columns.
So I have to parse for the correct row-ID in both sheets and the corresponding Column in both column headers.
I do not want to use a formula in the sheet, because I have to do the comparison in programmatical way.

Could someone please give me a hint if there is a function, method or property in Excel I could use?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Hope It May Help You.
It compares and if in second sheet any change from first sheet it will update the cell value and highlight it in yellow color.

```
Set objMyExcel = CreateObject(“Excel.Application”)
objExcel.Visible = False

Set objMyDataExcel1= objMyExcel.Workbooks.Open(“C:\Data1.xls”)
Set objMyDataExcel2= objMyExcel.Workbooks.Open(“C:\Data2.xls”)

Set objMyWorksheet1= objMyDataExcel1.Worksheets(1)
Set objMyWorksheet2= objMyDataExcel2.Worksheets(1)

For Each cell In objMyWorksheet1.UsedRange

   If cell.Value <> objMyWorksheet2.Range(cell.Address).Value Then

       objMyWorksheet2.Range(cell.Address).Value = cell.Value
       cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6

   Else

       cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 0

   End If

 Next

Set objMyExcel = Nothing
```

if you want to see the excel on execution time then set

```
objExcel.Visible = True
```